# Two way percentage formatted binding in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I have this textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TaxFactor, StringFormat=P}" />
```

It correctly displays `0.05` as `5%`, but it doesn't work going back. When I type in a percentage, it fails because of the percent symbol. If I try writing just a number, like `5`, I get `500%` instead. I have to write `0.05` for it to work.

Do I have to write a custom converter to get my percentage back? And if so, how do I get around locale-specific percentage formats?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to write a custom converter. NOTE: this one assumes that the values are stored in the range 0 to 100 rather than 0 to 1.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString())) return 0;

    if (value.GetType() == typeof(double)) return (double)value / 100;

    if (value.GetType() == typeof(decimal)) return (decimal)value / 100;    

    return value;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString())) return 0;

    var trimmedValue = value.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { '%' });

    if (targetType == typeof(double))
    {
        double result;
        if (double.TryParse(trimmedValue, out result))
            return result;
        else
            return value;
    }

    if (targetType == typeof(decimal))
    {
        decimal result;
        if (decimal.TryParse(trimmedValue, out result))
            return result;
        else
            return value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

The call it like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TaxFactor, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=P, 
         Converter={StaticResource percentStringFormatConverter} />
```

*this is from some Silverlight code, but should work with WPF*

Comment: Close enough for my current needs, although the converter needs some tweaking (it doesn't divide the number by 100) and ignores localization. Thanks.

Comment: @Ilia - ah, we store our percentages as numbers from 0 to 100 (don't ask me why) rather than 0 to 1. As for the localisation - it's supposed to cope - I'll have to double check this on our application (thanks for the heads up).

Comment: I posted the code I'm happy with as another answer. I'm guessing I could use the culture.NumberFormat.Percent* values for a more accurate parse, but this is good enough for me.

Comment: WPF's `ProgressBar` class uses the range 0 to 100. Perhaps that's why your codebase uses that over 0 to 1.

Comment: @emddudley - We're actually writing a Silverlight app :) plus the numbers aren't on a progress bar. But apart from that it's a good idea ;)

Answer (score 6):

Adding to ChrisF's answer, the converter I ended up using (only for decimals):

```
class DecimalPercentageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(decimal) || value == null)
            return value;

        string str = value.ToString();

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            return 0M;

        str = str.TrimEnd(culture.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol.ToCharArray());

        decimal result = 0M;
        if (decimal.TryParse(str, out result)) {
            result /= 100;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```