# Translating numeric value in DataTable for editing without marking as Modified

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a sql table which I read into a `DataTable`. One of the columns is a decimal proportion, but I would like value to be displayed as a percentage for user editing (*i.e.* multiplied by 100). Is there an easy way to perform this translation in a `DataGrid` (or somewhere else?) so that I don't have to iterate over every record to multiply by 100, display, then divide all by 100 at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that'd do for you but you could try setting the `StringFormat` - like in this one...

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Percentage, StringFormat={}{0:P2}}"/>
```

[Format decimal for percentage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790975/format-decimal-for-percentage-values)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx

Note: this one actually works :) - and e.g. it translates the `0.8555` into `85.55%` (add percent at will)

**EDIT:**
For a two way editing actually - you'd need a Converter.

You could use this one here [Two way percentage formatted binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968478/two-way-percentage-formatted-binding-in-wpf/4968527#4968527)

Comment: that's a culture specific - see this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/6567122/417747 - but I think that's easier then to make a converter for your percentage type. This answers your original question - if you need more, close this one and open another if you'd need more help.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't solve my problem - if I use this formatter, the TextBox still treats the value as a decimal proportion. *I.e.* if I type in **33** (user wants to input 33%) and tab out of the box, the resulting value in the box is **3300 %** which would be incorrect.

Comment: then you need a `Converter` - from decimal/double to string and back.

Comment: Actual you mentioned 'displayed', this is ok for displaying - but editing is a bit different.

Comment: The Converter is exactly what I was looking for - thanks for the pointer.