# How to put decimal value in textbox field?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to put decimal value in textbox? Example, I want to put value 0.20 or 20 but to be read as 20%?

Comment: so you want to format your value to a percent mask?

Comment: You can specify a `StringFormat` in your binding, as shown in the linked question. If you need something more advanced such as converting either "0.2" or "20" to a percent, you can use a `Converter`. For an example of a converter that only converts "20", check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4968478/302677) - you should be able to easily modify that to check for something like ".20" too.

Answer (score 1):

Because you should keep this kind of code out of your business logic, you might want to use a [`StringFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) combined with a custom value converter. [Please refer to this article.](http://syncor.blogspot.de/2011/12/displaying-and-editing-percentages-in.html)

In your case, the `TextBox` might - without knowing your code - look like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PercentValue, StringFormat=P, Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}}" />
```

The "P" here wold treat `0.25` as 25%.

Comment: Converter has to be imported as a resource to the XAML. Your answer is incomplete and yet copied without understand of how it works yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
        decimal val = 0M;
        decimal.TryParse(YourTextBox.Text, out val);
        decimal valAsPercent = val * 100;
        // Then when you want to stuff the new value back into your textbox
        YourTextBox.Text = valAsPercent.ToString() + "%";
```